# QGIS error code, trying to split a layer

Tags: qgis, polygon, error, features, splitting

I keep getting the error code below when trying to split a polygon. There appear to be no duplicates and I have been able to spilt other layers within the same shapefile. Can anyone give me any work arounds please.

Error message:

> No features were split: If there are selected features, the split tool
> only applies to those. If you would like to split all features under
> the split line, clear the selection.

So the highlighted polygon gets the error but the one above I can split no problem though both are from the same. I use the scissor tool highlighted. sorry new to all the terminology.

[image]

Comment: You are likely going to need to provide more information to get an answer. Is the polygn truly Polygon geometry, or is it MultiPolygon? What method are you using to split the polygon? What CRS is your layer, and does it match your project CRS? When you refer to "layers within the same shapefile", presumably you mean polygon features?

Comment: Lucy what does your polygon look like? There are a few reasons for this, we would need more information from you.

Comment: Thanks some of the polygons split fine then others won't and I get the fore mentioned error. My CRS is EPSG:27700 British national grid for both project and shapefiles. Just trying to figure out how to add a photo

Comment: It just be the way your screenshot is rendered, but, it appears the southernmost edge of the Polygon is darker than the rest. This may mean it has duplicate vertices (and therefore an identical, overlapping segment, mean the geometry is invalid). Try using the *Fix geometries* tool on your polygon layer and then continuing your splitting workflow on the output of that tool. Otherwise, there are various other ways to check the validity of the geometry (Topology checker plugin, for example).